# Placing glyph icon next to nav stacked items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a nav stacked list with checks in it like below. Is there any way I can move the checks to the right or left of the items so when the items are active they don't cover up the check?

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bav5n61a/)

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-right"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-right"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-right"></i></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean cover up the check? It looks fine to me. The .active class gives the anchor white text, so the tick is white
      on a blue background?

Comment: I didn't inlcude my css, but I make the check green, so with a blue background from the item being active it drowns out the green. It just seems like it would be nicer to have it next to the blue area of the active item, not inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the markup a bit, move it outside the anchor.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li role="presentation" class="active">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-right"></i>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#">Other</a>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-right"></i>
  </li>
</ul>

.nav .active {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav .active a {
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
}
.nav i {display:none;}
.nav .active i {
  margin: 12px 14px 0 0;
  display: block;
}
```

EDIT: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bav5n61a/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively add a white (or different colored) background to the checkmark when it's active by adding the following CSS:

```
.nav-pills>li.active>a i {
  color: green;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/karolbrennan/uc5xfsso/